# Linked List - Free() nodes causes program to crash

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I am new to linked lists in c and wrote a little program in c,  creating nodes and when I try to free the allocated memory my program crashes. I don't know what is causing this error, so I hope you can help me. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *link;
} node;
node *createnode();
int main()
{
    node *a = createnode(); //create first node
    node *start = a;
    printf("Value of first node: ");
    scanf("%d", &a->data);
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++) //create three nodes
    {
        a->link = createnode();
        a = a -> link;
        printf("Value of node %d: ", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &a->data);
        if(j==2)
        {
            a -> link = NULL;
        }
    }
    a = start;
    while(a != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", a->data);
        a = a -> link;
        if(a==NULL)
        {
            printf("null");
        }
    }
    a = start;
    while(a != NULL)
    {
        a = start;
        start = a -> link;
        free(a);
    }



    return 0;
}
node *createnode()
{
    return malloc(sizeof(node));
}
```

Comment: @kiner_shah no, `a->link = createnode(); ` is done the next loop, else there is a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

```
while(a != NULL)
{
    a = start;
    start = a -> link;
    free(a);
}
```

must be

```
while(start != NULL)
{
    a = start;
    start = a -> link;
    free(a);
}
```

and of course `a = start;` just before is useless

{edit}

additional remark, to do `if(j==2) { a -> link = NULL; }` is a bad choice, because just after you test again the value of *j* and if you have to change the number of loops you have to do 2 changes. Better to remove it and to add `a -> link = NULL;` directly after the loop (no test needed)

Comment: Thanks I got it! Yes you are right, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
    a = start;
    while(a != NULL)
    {
        a = start;
        start = a -> link;
        free(a);
    }
```

with:

```
    while(start != NULL)
    {
        a = start;
        start = a -> link;
        free(a);
    }
```

In the original loop, `a` was being set to the new value without being tested.